# java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["_source"] not found. #Kuzzle

Tags: kuzzle

I am trying to update the document using java sdk, when I run my code kuzzle status is connected, it update the fields but neither comes in onSuccess() nor onError(). when I again request to updateDocument(), kuzzle state change from connected to error. I debug the issue and found this exception. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["_source"] not found.

as I am not getting "_source" in my code

```
     kuzzle.collection("collection","testindex").updateDocument(obj.getDocumentId(), jsonObj, new ResponseListener<Document>() {
          @Override
          public void onSuccess(Document response) {
              System.out.println("success"+response);

          }

          @Override
          public void onError(JSONObject error) {
              System.out.println("error"+error);

          }
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

A fix has recently been released for this probleme. You should try with version 3.0.10 of the SDK: https://bintray.com/kuzzle/maven/kuzzle-sdk-android/3.0.10